# Fragment not launched from another fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment with two buttons: btnEdit and btnExamen.
Each button has an OnClickListener.
Here is the code:

```
btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);




                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();

                editor.putString("id_empleo","No");
                editor.putString("id_grado","No");


                editor.apply();

                HomeFragment firstFragment = new HomeFragment();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame, firstFragment).commit();

            }
        });

btnExamen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Iniciando examen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ExamenesFragment secondFragment = new ExamenesFragment();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

The issue is that the first method works fine, HomeFragment is launched.
But the second method is not launching fragment ExamFragment. The toast is launched.

I am not able to see any difference at the code that could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the current Fragment with the new Fragment and push transaction onto the backstack. This preserves back button behaviour...

Creating a new Activity really defeats the whole purpose to use fragments anyway...very counter productive.

```
    btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { 
...
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        HomeFragment firstFragment = new HomeFragment(); 
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the frame view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, firstFragment );
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();                  
                }
            });

    btnExamen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    ...

        ExamenesFragment secondFragment= new ExamenesFragment(); 
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame, secondFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
        transaction.commit();                   
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you, but same result, first method works fine and second method only launches the toast

Comment: Please see this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions) for more detail.